# MYSQL Group by Hour - showing zero results

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to generate a query which returns results by hour and which also shows zero results.

At the moment MYSQL statement only shows results where results exist rather than existing results and zero results.

**MYSQL SO FAR**

```
SELECT DATE(received) as Date, 
CONCAT(HOUR(received), ':00-', HOUR(received)+1, ':00') AS Hours, 
IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0) as Leads from digital_lead
where `received` BETWEEN '2014-11-01' AND '2014-11-25'
GROUP BY DATE(received), HOUR(received)
```

Currently this shows each day within the date range divided by hours, only where exists a `lead` for that hour-slot. I would like to show all of the hours within each day, even where no `lead` data exists for that hour.

**Example**

```
DATE         HOUR SLOT         LEADS 
2014-11-01   00:00 - 01:00      0
             01:00 - 02:00      0
             02:00 - 03:00      12 ... etc
```

I've had a look around on Stackoverflow and found this question which seems similar

[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372708/sql-count-to-include-zero-values)

From what I understand I need to create a separate table with 24 hour slots and JOIN that to my query to show `IFNULL(COUNT(*),0)` results in my query.

Can somebody please demonstrate how this would work in practice?

**UPDATE**

Using Strawberry's suggestions, below here is what I have now:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 00:00:00') + INTERVAL i2.i*10+i1.i HOUR today
      , COUNT(received) total
   FROM ints i1
  CROSS
   JOIN ints i2   
   LEFT
   JOIN digital_lead
     ON DATE_FORMAT(received,'%Y-%m-%d %h:00:00') = CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 00:00:00') + INTERVAL i2.i*10+i1.i HOUR
  WHERE received BETWEEN '2014-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-11-26 00:00:00'
  GROUP
     BY HOUR(received)
```

However, this isn't showing any results where I know there are some ...?

Comment: (In MySQL) You cannot 'select' data which is not present. You have to simulate it in some way - either with a utility table, or a UNION select, or, I suppose, a sproc - but issues of data presentation are generally best left to application level code.

Comment: @Strawberry - So `CONCAT(HOUR(received), ':00-', HOUR(received)+1, ':00') AS Hours,` will only SELECT the hours present within TIMESTAMP field rather than all 24 hours?

Comment: Well, yes (give or take an hour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't necessarily the solution that I'd advocate, but you asked to see an example along these lines...

I have a table of integers (0-9). I can join that to a string to make a list, like so...

```
 SELECT CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 00:00:00') + INTERVAL i HOUR today FROM ints;
 +---------------------+
 | today               |
 +---------------------+
 | 2014-11-26 00:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 01:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 02:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 03:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 04:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 05:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 06:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 07:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 08:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 09:00:00 |
 +---------------------+
```

If I want more than 10 items in my list, I can just join the integers multiple times, like so...

```
 SELECT CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 00:00:00') + INTERVAL i2.i*10+i1.i HOUR today FROM ints i1,ints i2 HAVING DATE(today) = DATE(CURDATE());
 +---------------------+
 | today               |
 +---------------------+
 | 2014-11-26 00:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 01:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 02:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 03:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 04:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 05:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 06:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 07:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 08:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 09:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 10:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 11:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 12:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 13:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 14:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 15:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 16:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 17:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 18:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 19:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 20:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 21:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 22:00:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 23:00:00 |
 +---------------------+
```

If you don't like the overhead of maintaining a utility table (some people seem not to - weird), you can also substutute the utility table with a list that you create on the fly - `SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2`, etc.

Now you simply OUTER JOIN your source data, something like this...

```
 SELECT * FROM my_table;
 +---------------------+
 | dt                  |
 +---------------------+
 | 2014-11-26 03:15:35 |
 | 2014-11-26 03:17:32 |
 | 2014-11-26 04:19:01 |
 | 2014-11-26 09:44:11 |
 | 2014-11-26 09:54:00 |
 | 2014-11-26 09:59:30 |
 | 2014-11-26 12:07:24 |
 | 2014-11-26 12:07:26 |
 | 2014-11-26 13:01:15 |
 | 2014-11-26 17:00:00 |
 +---------------------+


  SELECT CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 00:00:00') + INTERVAL i2.i*10+i1.i HOUR today
       , COUNT(dt) total
    FROM ints i1
   CROSS
    JOIN ints i2
    LEFT
    JOIN my_table x
      ON DATE(dt) = DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 00:00:00') + INTERVAL i2.i*10+i1.i HOUR)
     AND HOUR(dt) = HOUR(CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 00:00:00') + INTERVAL i2.i*10+i1.i HOUR)
   WHERE DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 00:00:00') + INTERVAL i2.i*10+i1.i HOUR) = CURDATE()
   GROUP
      BY CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 00:00:00') + INTERVAL i2.i*10+i1.i HOUR;
 +---------------------+-------+
 | today               | total |
 +---------------------+-------+
 | 2014-11-26 00:00:00 |     0 |
 | 2014-11-26 01:00:00 |     0 |
 | 2014-11-26 02:00:00 |     0 |
 | 2014-11-26 03:00:00 |     2 |
 | 2014-11-26 04:00:00 |     1 |
 | 2014-11-26 05:00:00 |     0 |
 | 2014-11-26 06:00:00 |     0 |
 | 2014-11-26 07:00:00 |     0 |
 | 2014-11-26 08:00:00 |     0 |
 | 2014-11-26 09:00:00 |     3 |
 | 2014-11-26 10:00:00 |     0 |
 | 2014-11-26 11:00:00 |     0 |
 | 2014-11-26 12:00:00 |     2 |
 | 2014-11-26 13:00:00 |     1 |
 | 2014-11-26 14:00:00 |     0 |
 | 2014-11-26 15:00:00 |     0 |
 | 2014-11-26 16:00:00 |     0 |
 | 2014-11-26 17:00:00 |     1 |
 | 2014-11-26 18:00:00 |     0 |
 | 2014-11-26 19:00:00 |     0 |
 | 2014-11-26 20:00:00 |     0 |
 | 2014-11-26 21:00:00 |     0 |
 | 2014-11-26 22:00:00 |     0 |
 | 2014-11-26 23:00:00 |     0 |
 +---------------------+-------+
```

Remember, I said I wouldn't necessarily advocate this as a solution ;-)

Comment: Thanks - So if I created a utility as above would I  SELECT the data from this data and JOIN my query to that?

Comment: Yes. It just means adding an OUTER JOIN to the above.

Comment: Sorry - could you edit your answer to show the combined result of my original query with the OUTER JOIN of the ints table. I'm having trouble realising the final solution...

Comment: I don't have any source data.

Comment: What would you require? Thanks

Comment: Ok - so this works fine for today. How do I adjust to make this work for the date range that I pass in so that it would show the result by hour for the days between say ... `2014-11-01 00:00:00 to 2014-11-26 00:00:00` ? Thanks

Comment: So, remember I mentioned about joining the utility table to itself? Well do that, and change WHERE... = CURDATE() to WHERE... BETWEEN 'x' AND 'y'

Comment: If you wouldn't advocate it as a solution, why are you suggesting it? Ha :) Please see my edit above - this isn't generating any results. Where have I gone wrong? Thanks

Comment: Um, you specifically asked for an example !?! Without proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle), it's almost impossible for me to comment on code - although re-read my edit - there are some divergences from your code)